# Regularization of underdetermined system to favour low frequency solutions?

Tags: regularization

Consider the ill-posed system
$$ \mathbf A \mathbf x= \mathbf b.$$

One method to regularize the solution is the Tikhonov method which effectively minimizes $ ||\mathbf A \mathbf x - \mathbf b ||^2 + || \mathbf \Gamma  \mathbf x||^2$.

Letting the Tikhonov matrix $\mathbf \Gamma = \lambda \mathbf I$ favours solutions with smaller norms, where $\mathbf I$ is the identity matrix, and the parameter $\lambda$ is chosen empirically of a given system. Singular value decomposition ($\mathbf A = \mathbf{U \Sigma V}^H$) may then be used to calculate the solution via $\mathbf x = \mathbf{V \hat{\Sigma} U}^H \mathbf b$, where

$$\hat{\Sigma}_{ii} = \frac{\Sigma_{ii}}{\Sigma_{ii}^2 + \lambda^2}.$$

My question is how to find $\mathbf x$ which instead favours low frequency solutions?

*i.e.* I wish to minimize something like $ ||\mathbf A \mathbf x - \mathbf b ||^2 + \lambda^2  \sum_{high \, frequencies} FFT \{ \mathbf x \}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems like you said how to do it:
Let $ T $ be the discrete fourier transform matrix, ie. something like:
$$
T_{a,b} = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{N} ab}
$$
or whatever is appropriate for your situation. Then let $ P $ be the projection on to high frequency modes, or more generally something like $ P =  \text{diag}(0,0,\cdots,w_{n-2},w_{n-1},w_{n}) $. For some weights $ w_i $ you can choose. Then let $ \Gamma = PT $.

Maybe there is some natural choice for the weights. For example, it might be computationally easier if you take $ \Gamma $ to be some finite difference matrix, eg:
$$
\Gamma = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots  \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & \cdots \\ && \ddots & \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks, the comment about a finite difference matrix was especially helpful. I also forgot that I can use $x=(A^HA +\Gamma^H \Gamma)^{-1} A^H b$ in place of SVD.